# application authentication API

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, aws-api-gateway

Iam a student and i making my internship. Sorry for my bad englis

**The situation**

2 people are building an backend for an message system. There are actual and passed messages. The main backend contains all the data from all the messages. This backend pushes only actual messages to and database from an mini backend which only contains the actual alerts. These actual alerts are provided by an api to multiple front ends such as an app.

I need to do research about api gateways which can make the data in the mini backend accesable for external developers. These developers only need to register or request an account so we know which application/developer connects with our api. We don't have end users with user accounts.

The API need to be scalable because in the future (over a couple of months) this system wil replace an old system. The current system needs to be handle more then 5.000.000 requests in a couple of minutes when sending out an emergency message/alert.

[image]

**My problem**

I googled a lot about authentication methods and i read about OAuth2. This is only necessary for authenticate end users with an user account? I dont have that so OAuth is to complex for my situation i think. But when i look in the documentation of several API Gateways like Mulesoft, Amazon API Gateway and some more i always come back by OAuth and not by an simple authentication token system or something.

See [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/creating-an-oauth-2.0a-web-service-provider#creating-a-client-registration-flow) link and then Creating a client registration flow. This uses OAuth or do i understand this incorrectly?

**So now my questions**

- Is there an default method such as google or facebook uses for authenticate external applications by an API key? and how is this method/framwork/idunno caled?
- Is it posible that i can/need to do this with OAuth?

Some example API gateways that can fill in my wishes will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Api Gateway team here.

Our service supports native API keys which satisfy simple use cases. Are you interested in a simple mechanism to authenticate clients when they access your API? Some limitations would be that it's harder to manage a large number of keys, and there wouldn't really be any authorization to specific backend resources, only authentication to access the API in general.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html

OAuth is better for dynamic user bases where new users register and you want to be able to control access for existing users over time. It is also useful when users have personal data that only they should be able to access.

Jack

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,
What do you mean with "better for dynamic user bases" 

We want that external developers need do create an account. This account is linked to an API key which gives acces to our service(API).

So when i understand you correctly i need OAuth for that? The API key system what is described in your documentation doens't make this posible?

Comment: I guess my point is that Api Keys are static and you'd have to manage creating/configuring/distributing those yourself. Also Api Keys could be distributed to multiple clients. OAuth is a different solution that manages temporary tokens and can be used to authenticate a specific user in your backend database. It sounds to me like Api Keys will work for your use case if you want to essentially hand out static access keys to your service.

Comment: Something else to think about, the relationship between Api Keys and your users' identities would have to be managed by your service right? If you're planning to use Api Keys to identify your users in your backend (pass the Api Key all the way through) then I would say OAuth would be a more secure solution since users have to authenticate themselves to get a token, then use that token for a finite period of time. If not, if you're just using Api Keys as random keys for your clients and you aren't using them as identifiers, then Api Keys are perfect.

Comment: Thanks, i think i use API keys. In our situation the data is public but we want that it is posible to block users when they make to many requests or do bad things with our data. We will also monitor who maken how many request and so on. Thanks for the detailed explaination, exacly what i needed!